# Emgu cv high resolution images stitching Issue

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am using EmguCV library to stitch images. Its working fine for small images but getting exception when processing high resolution images or images above 20MB size or even if I try to process more than 30 images it fails.

**Libraries I am using**

```
Emgu.CV.UI
Emgu.CV.UI.GL
Emgu.CV.World
opencv_core2410
opencv_imgproc2410
```

**Code**

```
List<Image<Bgr, Byte>> sourceImages = new List<Image<Bgr,byte>>();
foreach (string path in ImgPath)
    sourceImages.Add(new Image<Bgr, Byte>(path));
using (Stitcher stitcher = new Stitcher(false))
{
    using (VectorOfMat vm = new VectorOfMat())
    {
        Mat result = new Mat();
        vm.Push(sourceImages.ToArray());
        stitcher.Stitch(vm, result);
        if (result.Bitmap != null)
        {
            result.Bitmap.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\\imgs\\StitchedImage.png");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Some thing went wrong"); return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
((Emgu.CV.MatDataAllocator)(result))._dataHandle.Target' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException
```

**Image**
[image]
[image]

Comment: replace the screen shot with text of the full error message - make us sad otherwise...

Comment: @JohnB i also write down error message in exception heading

Comment: ok, i have submitted an edit - just the text is better

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? What line is this exception occurring on? I would guess the issue is memory related based on your description, but a stack trace might help. Are you getting the exception on this line `Mat result = new Mat();` or is it occurring when you are stitching things?

Comment: Another question - when you say it fails when trying to process more than 30 images - do you mean that if you try to stitch together more than 30 small images it fails, or do you mean that if you stitch together a bunch of small images more than 30 times it will fail? Are you disposing of the images in your `List`?  When you say it fails on images that are 20 MB in size, do you mean that if you are loading up a bunch of 20 MB images and then stitching them it fails? Can you please provide more details of how you are running this code and how/when it is failing. Is this a 32 bit app?

Comment: @pstrjds i am not getting any exception in code. but i got result.Bitmap = null
when i debug i came to know there is some exception which i mentioned in question. honestly speaking i dont know which line of code is generating this exception at backend,
and secondly brother i am trying to stitch more then 30 images. all images are in list and i pass that list to vectorOfMat (vm) .

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar - So there is no exception thrown that you are able to catch and dump out the stack trace? Is there a way to enable logging in the EmguCV library, like maybe passing in a log4net logger or something like that? Also, you didn't really answer my question about when it fails. Can you process a smaller number of large images? Can you process 30+ small images? Are you running 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar - I have updated my answer with different sample data and an explanation of what I believe is going wrong.

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar - I added several more comments and questions and moved the discussion to chat. Please followup with me there.

Answer (score 0):

I was fairly certain that you are running into a memory issue and so I went ahead and made a simple console app targeting .Net 4.7.2, using the latest [EmguCV](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EMGU.CV/) package from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/), which is version 3.4.3.3016, and using the code below on sample data from Adobe, which can be downloaded [here](https://sourceforge.net/adobe/adobedatasets/panoramas/home/Home/).  If I compile as "AnyCPU" with "prefer 32 bit" and run this code against the `rio` image set (I loaded up the png's for the test purposes) and let it run the memory will slowly jump up until it hits close to 3 GB and then shortly thereafter crashes giving the exception about the refcount.  Pretty clearly a memory issue. I then recompiled targeting 64 bit and was able to successfully run the code.  The memory usage peaked out around 6 GB.  So, with that in mind, I would be fairly certain that your issue is also memory related. You have yet to answer the question on whether you are building a 64 bit app or not, but based on what you are seeing, I would guess that you are not.  So, the solution to your problem is to compile as 64 bit and then be sure you have enough memory.  With the `rio` test set it jumped up to close to 6 GB.  Without having your images I can't tell you how large it might grow, but these type of operations are pretty memory intensive - so more is better.  This would explain both the issue with large image files and the issue with a large number of small image files.  I was able to successfully process sets of images that were between 10 and 20 images using a 32 bit build, but as soon as I moved to the 50+ image sets it would only work with a 64 bit build due to the memory requirements.

```
var images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\test\adobe\rio", "*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(x => new Mat(x)).ToArray();
using(var stitcher = new Stitcher(false))
{
    using (var vm = new VectorOfMat(images))
    {
        var result = new Mat();
        stitcher.Stitch(vm, result);
        result.Bitmap.Save(@"C:\test\adobe\rio_stitched.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        result.Dispose();
    }
}
foreach (var image in images) { image.Dispose(); }
```

Comment: x => new Mat(x)).ToArray() this statement is throwing error. Matric constructor with one argument not defined. i changed it to x => new Mat()).ToArray() then got exception at stitcher.Stitch(vm, result);

   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvErrorHandler(Int32 status, IntPtr funcName, IntPtr errMsg, IntPtr fileName, Int32 line, IntPtr userData)
   at Emgu.CV.Stitching.StitchingInvoke.CvStitcherStitch(IntPtr stitcherWrapper, IntPtr images, IntPtr pano)
   at Emgu.CV.Stitching.Stitcher.Stitch(IInputArray images, IOutputArray pano)

Comment: i tried x => new Mat(x,LoadImageType.Color)).ToArray() . it worked but again got exception while stitching  ...  (OpenCV: u != 0)     at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvErrorHandler(Int32 status, IntPtr funcName, IntPtr errMsg, IntPtr fileName, Int32 line, IntPtr userData)
   at Emgu.CV.Stitching.StitchingInvoke.CvStitcherStitch(IntPtr stitcherWrapper, IntPtr images, IntPtr pano)
   at Emgu.CV.Stitching.Stitcher.Stitch(IInputArray images, IOutputArray pano)

Comment: i have 7 images all of size 15MB

Comment: SOme times i am getting this ... OpenCV: u->refcount == 0 && "UMat deallocation error: some derived Mat is still alive"


   at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvErrorHandler(Int32 status, IntPtr funcName, IntPtr errMsg, IntPtr fileName, Int32 line, IntPtr userData)
   at Emgu.CV.Stitching.StitchingInvoke.CvStitcherRelease(IntPtr& stitcherWrapper)
   at Emgu.CV.Stitching.Stitcher.DisposeObject()
   at Emgu.Util.DisposableObject.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Emgu.Util.DisposableObject.Dispose()

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar   This code compiles just fine for me.  What version of the toolkit are you using? 
 What .Net framework are you targeting.  64 or 32 bit?  Can you post the images so I could test with it to see if I can reproduce the issue?  By the way, I am using toolkit version 3.4.3

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar - When you say "15 MB" as the size of the image. What format are they in? Is that 15 MB as a raw file or a BMP or is it a 15 MB jpeg? What are the pixel dimensions of the images?

Comment: I am using Emgu.CV Version 3.1.0.2282  and i run this code on both 32bit and 64 bit. but got same issue.Yes 15 MB is size of one image and image format is PNG.And pixel dimensions are 1287 x 7864 . this is smallest image among 7 images.

Comment: I used Emgucv 3.4.3 and your code. Now i face exactly same situation as i mentioned in my question.
"Handler is not initialized" .. this time i debug each line and i quick watch every statement and i found this. i am adding one more image in question kindly check it.

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar - Does it happen on the same image every time? Are all of those images valid PNG images? Once you have verified that all your PNGs are valid PNGS images, then I feel like if you are having this problem with a 64 bit build and the latest toolkit, then you need to reach out to either the EmguCV team or the OpenCV team. I would try downloading the EmguCV source and building it yourself. Then you should be able to step into that code when debugging your program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183541/discussion-between-pstrjds-and-zohaib-waqar).